# Can't access to extern variable from another class

Tags: objective-c, phonegap-plugins

I've created a phonegap plugin to give a variable to native code. That works fine. Now I need to access to this value from other classes so I decided to create an extern NSString.

.h

```
extern NSString  *lkwid;

@interface MyPlugin : CDVPlugin {

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *lkwid;    
-(void) setMyValue:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
```

.m

```
#import "MyPlugin.h"

@implementation MyPlugin

@synthesize lkwid;

NSString *lkwid = @"";


-(void) setMyValue:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {
    NSString* callbackId = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    lkwid = callbackId;
    NSLog(@"set value %@ ",lkwid);
    //NSLog shows the correct value from Javascript
}
```

Now I want to access to `lkwid` from MainViewController.m (MyPlugin.h is imported) but lkwid is empty. Why?

Comment: Are you sure your use of `lkwid` in your MainViewController is happening *after* a call to `MyPlugin setMyValue:withDict:`?

Comment: Side note - it would be clearer if you moved `NSString *lkwid = @"";` to be outside of the `@implementation`. It is a global variable and is not tied in any way to the class.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confusing instance variables and static (class) variables. The `extern NSString *lkwid` declares a globally accessible variable. `@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *lkwid` declares an instance variables to your object. If you want it to set the global variable, which would then be shared by *ALL* the instances, then you should not synthesize the property andimplement the getter and setter yourself in the following manner:

```
- (NSString*) lkwid
{
    return lkwid;
}

- (void) setLkwid:(NSString*)value
{
    lkwid = value;
}
```

Make sure that you don't also declare an instance variable with the name `lkwid`.

Comment: I think that it should but you must still implement the getter and setter manually.

Comment: Ok I did delete the two points and created getter and setter. But how do I have to init the class inside of MainViewController so that the class is an instance over all methodes in MainViewCOntroller class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking how to initialize lkwid? If so it would be in the init method if MyPlugin. In the init method if MainViewController you would create an instance of MyPlugin with a line of code like `_myplugin = [[MyPlugin alloc] init]`. But since you did not declare lkwid as a constant, you don't event need the plugin. You can just do `lwkid = @"Hello"` anywhere to set the value (you should probably declare it as a constant though).

Comment: With delclare lkwid as a constant I can access, thanks. But I got the warning (which crash the app by call) that: "Initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of type 'const NSSting *' discards qualifiers". How can I convert const String to normal NSString?

Comment: It's my mistake. If you want to be able to change it it obviously can't be a constant!